# How to center a fixed div inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I have one main div that should make the page scrollable. On either side of this div there is a sidebar. The only difference I want from how it is now, is that the sidebars should always stay on top (`position: fixed;`)

I've tried everything, but it doesn't work. If I put `position: fixed;` on the `.fixed`, the width is no longer 100 % but the width of the actual contents inside. If I put on `width: 100%` the width turns 100 % of the viewport.

Is this even possible with just CSS?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6yWNv/

Sidebar 1

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="contents">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amnet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="contents">
        <div class="fixed">
            Sidebar 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

```
#wrapper {
    width: 54%;
    float: left;
    background: #0FF;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 23%;
    float: left;
}
.sidebar .contents {
    margin: auto;
    background: #F00;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100px;
}

.sidebar .contents .fixed {
    background: #0F0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have something floated and fixed at the same time

Comment: Is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6yWNv/2/?

Comment: Or perhaps this? http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/6yWNv/3/

Comment: No I tweaked the CSS a bit. Compare my CSS to yours. If that's what you want I'll post it as an answer with an explanation.

Comment: @j08691 Actually John Kurlak pointed out that what I wanted wasn't possible with just CSS, so I'll just have to do the next best, which is probably your solution. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering why this question is voted down? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible with just CSS.  When you make an element `fixed`, it removes it from its "context" and makes its new "context" the document.  That's why specifying `width: 100%` on the `position: fixed` element spans the page.

Edit: I'm assuming that you want the green sidebars to stay in place but the red boxes to move away as you scroll (I'm making this assumption because of the way you've named your classes on your page).

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to set `position:fixed` on the sidebar (with `left:0` and `right:0` respectively) and then add `margin-left:23%` to `#wrapper`:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 54%;
    margin-left: 23%;
    background: #0FF;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 23%;
    position: fixed;
    left:0; top: 0;
}

#wrapper + .sidebar {  /* target second sidebar */
    left: inherit;     /* reset left */
    right:0;
}
```

if you want the green sidebars to stay in place, but the red boxes to move away, then something like this should work:

```
.sidebar {
    width: 23%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;   /* so sub-containers are relative to sidebar */
}
.sidebar .contents {
    margin: auto;
    background: #F00;
    min-width: 100px;
    width: 100%;          /* relative to sidebar */
    height: 100px;
}

.sidebar .contents .fixed {
    background: #0F0;
    position: fixed;      /*  starts a new context... */
    width: 23%;           /*  so this is not relative to sidebar *.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to *fix* the `sidebar`, not its contents.

Just remove the `float` and set the position fixed to top and right

```
  .sidebar {
        width: 30%;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        right:0;
    }
```