# How to center a div fixed over another?

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, overlay, centering

I am trying to center a `div` (`overlay`) over another. I've managed to center it *inside* the `div`. But then it will be cut off and not stick to the center when the content of the parent is scrolled. Unfortunately, the `overlay` cannot just be set to fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20621323/1981832.

Here is my code so far:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjyYwV

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to get what I wanted. However, I consider it non-ideal since it needs an additional `wrapper` element.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="parent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this. Also you'll have to add wrapper that will occupy content's width and height and move text to some tag (i.e. `span`):

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.flex {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex; /* Width fit content */
  min-width: 100%; /* Not less than parent's width */
  min-height: 100%; /* Not less than parent's height */
  justify-content: center; /* Center items horizontally */
  align-items: center;  /* Center items vertically */
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="flex">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</span>
      <div class="overlay"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I never used `flexbox`. However, it seems not to work. The overlay still does (1) not stick when scrolling horizontally and (2) gets cut off. Also the text content of the parent differently vertically aligned.

Comment: No, that seems to be a misunderstanding. I want it to stick to the center. But I commented that in your first suggestion it did not.